# finding an equation of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the lines:

$l_1: (1,-2,5)+t(2,1,-1)$

$l_2: (3,4,1)+s(2,1,-1)$.

Need to find the equation of the plane that is equally distance from those two lines, and Perpendicular to a plane that those lines creates.

**My attempt:**

I can see that the lines are parallels. i tried to find the equation of the plane that the two lines form but i don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite the two lines as follows
$$
\begin{gathered}
  l_{\,1} :\mathbf{a} + t\,\mathbf{v} = \left( {1, - 2,5} \right) + t\left( {2,1, - 1} \right) \hfill \\
  l_{\,2} :\mathbf{b} + t\,\mathbf{v} = \left( {3,4,1} \right) + s\left( {2,1, - 1} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
so that it is clear the definition of the two points $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ and vector $\mathbf v$.
Then as you correctly noted, being the vector $\mathbf v$ the same, the lines are parallel.
Consider now the segment joining the points  $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ and the relevant difference vector
$$
\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{a} = \left( {2,6, - 4} \right) = 2\left( {1,3, - 2} \right)
$$
The plane $\pi _{\,//} $ containing the two lines, shall contain both points and be parallel to $\mathbf v$,
i.e. it shall pass by one of the points and be normal to the vector
$$
\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{v} = \left( { - 2, - 2, - 4} \right) =  - 2\left( {1,1,2} \right)
$$
and since the vector $\mathbf n$ is not null, the two lines are distinct.

Now the required plane $\pi _{\, \bot } $ shall clearly be:
 - orthogonal to  $\pi _{\,//} $, i.e. parallel to $\mathbf n$
 - parallel to the lines, i.e. parallel to $\mathbf v$
 - equidistant from the lines, i.e. passing through the mid-point of the segment $\mathbf b - \mathbf a$

which means:
 - orthogonal to the vector $\mathbf{m} = \mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{v} = \left( { - 3,5, - 1} \right)$
 - passing through the point $\left( {\mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a}} \right)/2 = \left( {2,1,3} \right)$

So we get
$$
\pi _{\, \bot } :\left( {x - 2,y - 1,z - 3} \right) \cdot \left( { - 3,5, - 1} \right) = 0
$$

Comment: thank you! i think i got it. the plane is $8x-11y+5z-20=0$

Comment: @mila: uhm, does not look correct. If you develop the dot product in my reply you get $3x-5y+z-4=0$. Where did you get your equation from ?

Comment: for the point on the new line i did average of $(1,-2,5), (3,4,1)$ so i got: $(2,1,3)$. that line as the same direction as two lines so the line is: $(2,1,3)+k(2,1,-1)$, or $(2+2k,1+k,3-k)$. then i  subtract the point $(1,-2,5)$ so i got : $u=(2+2k-1,1+k+2,3-k-5)$. then i used the dot product: $u \cdot (2,1,-1)=0$, which gave me: $(8,-11,5)$. so $8x-11y+5z+d=0$, then i put:$(2,1,3)$ and got $8x-11y+5z-20=0$

Comment: @mila: "Then I subtract the point $ (1,-2,5)$" what does that mean ?

Comment: for the direction

Answer (score 0):

Hint the equation of plane containing two lines is $(r-a_1). (b_1×b_2) $ where $a_1$ can be any of the two points. And $b_1,b_2$ are two vectors. Now find the point on the required plane which is at same distance from both lines. This can be done like $x-1=|x-3|$ same with $y,z $ to get the point as $-1,-3,3$ now this plane is perpendicular to other plane containing the lines which means the normals are perpendicular so let drs of normal of unknown plane be $l,m,n $ we can get drs of normal of other plane ie plane containing lines from the above mentioned equation to get $ll_1+mm_1+nn_1=0$ get ratios in terms of $l$  of $l,m,n $ . Equation of a plane is also $lx+my+nz=d $ where $l,m,n $ are drs and $d $ is a constant . This plane passes through $(-1,-3,3) $ to get the required plane.